# Store ResultSet variable as a service

Tags: mysql, web-services, netbeans, resultset

I am using NetBeans to write the code of a web service here is the code of the operation :

```
/**
 * Get the products data 
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "getProducts")
public String[] getProducts() throws Exception {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/commerce","root","");
    PreparedStatement stat;
    stat = con.prepareStatement("select * from products");

    ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery();
    String tab[] = new String[5];
    while(result.next())
    {
        System.out.println(tab[0]= result.getString(1));
        System.out.println(tab[1]= result.getString(2));
        System.out.println(tab[2]= result.getString(3));
        System.out.println(tab[3]= result.getString(4));
        System.out.println(tab[4]= result.getString(5));  
    } 
    return tab;
}
```

So I just want to store the result of variable "result" and to return the data of the table, I tried to make the operation return a `ResultSet` variable, but I got an error, with the code above I just get the last entry of the database and that's logic because only the last values of the loop are stored so I want to know if there is a method to return the data in a structure so I can use it in the client project (Java EE)